# Modularize optaplanner benchmark config

Tags: xml, optaplanner

#### The question is:

**Is there a way to write a solver config file that it contains insertions of configuration parts from other xml-files within Optaplanner?**

#### Explanation:

I try to perform some rather complex benchmark runs with partially very different solver confugrations like different

- local search stages
- filter classes
- drool rule sets
- *etc.*

Because of that the template way shown in this [benchmark constraints salvation video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JpcPEieU3Cg&list=PLJY69IMbAdq0uKPnjtWXZ2x7KE1eWg3ns&index=30) is not sufficient.

Since XML has the DTD Entity insertion, I thought about modularize the complex configuration patterns and reuse them in different sets, but unfortunately Optaplanner seems not to support this feature when it is reading a solver configuration file.

```sh
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unmarshalling of benchmarkConfigResource (path/to/my/benchmarkConfig.xml) fails..
...
---- Debugging information ----
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.StreamException
cause-message       : 
class               : org.optaplanner.core.config.solver.SolverConfig
required-type       : org.optaplanner.core.config.solver.SolverConfig
converter-type      : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ReflectionConverter
line number         : 42
class[1]            : org.optaplanner.benchmark.config.SolverBenchmarkConfig
class[2]            : org.optaplanner.benchmark.config.PlannerBenchmarkConfig
version             : 1.4.10
-------------------------------
...
```

---

#### Example

The Idea is to have a conifg file directory somewhat like this:

```sh
|--- benchmarkConfig.xml
|--- header.xml
|--- scoreDirectorFactory_1.xml
|--- scoreDirectorFactory_2.xml
|--- ...
|--- localSearch_tabuSearch.xml
|--- localSearch_hillClimber.xml
|--- ...
```

And a `benchmarkConfig.xml` in the form of this

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plannerBenchmark [
        <!ENTITY header SYSTEM "header.xml">
        <!ENTITY scoreDirectorFactory_1 SYSTEM "scoreDirectorFactory_1.xml">
        <!ENTITY scoreDirectorFactory_2 SYSTEM "scoreDirectorFactory_2.xml">
        <!ENTITY localSearch_tabuSearch SYSTEM "localSearch_tabuSearch.xml">
        <!ENTITY localSearch_hillClimber SYSTEM "localSearch_hillClimber.xml">
        ]>
<plannerBenchmark>
    ...
    <inheritedSolverBenchmark>
        ...

        <solver>
            &header;
        </solver>
    </inheritedSolverBenchmark>


    <solverBenchmark>
        <name>SDF1-TabuSearch</name>
        &scoreDirectorFactory_1;
        <localSearch>
            &localSearch_tabuSearch;
        </localSearch>
    </solverBenchmark>

    <solverBenchmark>
        <name>SDF1-TabuSearch-HillClimber</name>
        &scoreDirectorFactory_1;
        <localSearch>
            &localSearch_tabuSearch;
        </localSearch>
        <localSearch>
            &localSearch_hillClimber;
        </localSearch>
    </solverBenchmark>

    <solverBenchmark>
        <name>SDF1-HillClimber</name>
        &scoreDirectorFactory_1;
        <localSearch>
            &localSearch_hillClimber;
        </localSearch>
    </solverBenchmark>

    <solverBenchmark>
        <name>SDF2-TabuSearch</name>
        &scoreDirectorFactory_2;
        <localSearch>
            &localSearch_tabuSearch;
        </localSearch>
    </solverBenchmark>

    ...

</plannerBenchmark>
```

Like that the usage of the benchmark system of Optaplanner would be pretty powerfull, IMHO.

Comment: DTD's are brittle. XInclude might work - that depends on XStream - but I 've never tried it.

Comment: I tried it with Xinclude too and was not successful.
But I am not an expert with xml so...

Answer (score 0):

It's not direclty supported, but given that:

- (if a freemarker template is used, that outputs XML)
- the XML input directly translates into plain old java classes, through XStream. The root class is [PlannerBenchmarkConfig](https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner/blob/master/optaplanner-benchmark/src/main/java/org/optaplanner/benchmark/config/PlannerBenchmarkConfig.java)
- and you can programmatically add and remove elements etc on those java classes, instead of going through XML. Some of those elements you add, you could read from xml too.
- In the end, you can call `PlannerBenchmarkFactory.create(PlannerBenchmarkConfig benchmarkConfig)` which returns a PlannerBenchmarkFactory.

it should be doable. I see no reason why it wouldn't work.

Comment: PS: I love it how you call my video a **salvation** video.

Comment: I think I mixed up **satisfaction** with ***salvation*** while remembering the title. ;D

Thank You for your answer.  I will try it out. 
And thank You for your project,